# Default Resource bundle is used for every locale?

Tags: java, locale, resourcebundle

I have a web page the content on which is using the values from the Default Resource bundle for every locale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used as a **fallback** bundle when no resource bundle could be located for a given Locale. You can specify a fallback locale. If none is specified then the default Locale of the JVM (`Locale.getDefault()`) is used as the fallback locale.

Tutorial: [Localization with ResourceBundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html)

Comment: The other resource bundle is available but stil the default one is selected.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal then either your bundle naming is not correct or your locale resolution is not working correctly. I suggest you read the tutorial I added to my post.

Comment: Unfortunately this link is no longer available. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html might be a good replacement.